# Автоматический деплой Docker-приложения

Tags: docker, непрерывная-интеграция

Разбираясь с докером возник вопрос как настроить автоматический деплой на удаленный сервер. Для билда образов использую gitlab хотелось бы что бы после того как коммит улетел на сервер автоматически сбилдился образ и задеплоился, в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: nomad, rancher, kubernetes, aurora, marathon

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какая инфраструктура управления контейнерами. Самый простой вариант на вскидку, если у вас билд идет через гитлаб, то можно добавить в gitlab-ci.yml:

```
pushimage: 
    script: docker push mytestimage
update_docker:
    script: ssh somehost "docker stop somename && docker pull mytestimage && docker run -d somename"
```